# What decides if a faceoff is Won or Lost?

Tags: statistics, ice-hockey

[image]

How is a [Faceoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face-off) decided as a won faceoff, or a lost faceoff? Is it all which center get the puck where he wants, or is it decided by another factor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not determined until possession is determined.

While it is possible that a center will win the faceoff by succeeding to draw the puck back to one of his teammates, if his team cannot maintain possession through the ensuing play, then the other team is awarded the faceoff won.